# DAX get Tabular name in PowerBI Report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a tabular live connection on Power BI. I want to display connection name/Tabular model name in PowerBI report. Any idea how to achieve same?

Comment: I would just add a table into the Tabular model with that information. I’m not aware of other options

Comment: that will not work for dynamic cases.

Comment: why not? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to show server name where tabular model is deloyed lets say I have 2 servers name UAT01 and PROD01. Per your soln, I will have say static value like UAT01 in one dim table but how will it change when I deploy it to PROD01 it will still show me UAT01. I want to show current server on which Model is deployed.

Comment: what relational Database do you load from? If you put @@servername in the SQL query would that indicate UAT vs. Prod?

Comment: SQL Query is gives source server name, I need to get server name where model is deployed

Comment: not possible that I know of